# How to start of commands with auto response to prompt in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying the following:

```
start /wait /B "C:\Users\Kiriti_Komaragiri\Desktop\sample" npm i
echo Y
start /wait /B "C:\Users\Kiriti_Komaragiri\Desktop\sample2" npm i
```

I would like to run the above in the same window with auto response "Y"

Currently, its running only the first command and not the third one. I am not sure why?

Comment: try with `echo Y|start /wait /B "C:\Users\Kiriti_Komaragiri\Desktop\sample2" npm i`

Comment: What is `C:\Users\Kiriti_Komaragiri\Desktop\sample`? the path to an executable or just a window title? if the former, explicitly state a (blank) window title like `start "" /WAIT /B ...` to avoid misinterpretation of the given command line...

Answer (score 0):

More information please. What type of command are you trying to feed the response to? Is it Choice, Set /p, or something else your trying to feed a response to?

Without knowing more, the only suggestion I can make requires the existence of a label before the input is processed in the secondary batch.

A workaround exists whereby you can call and arrive at a label in another Batch by calling a label with the same name in your calling Batch. This allows you to define the value of the input (Whatever form the input takes) in your primary batch, then do as follows (substituting label names, variable names and file paths as appropriate)

-In the Calling (Primary) Batch:

```
Set ResponseVarName=Y

Call :targetLabel

(whatever code your batch has in between)

REM this is where you make your hack 'Call' to the other batch, without actually 'Calling' the batch itself.

:targetLabel
%userprofile%\desktop\yourotherbatch.bat
exit /b
```

Just to be sure your absolutely clear, this workaround is utterly dependant on being sent to a specific label after the response is set, BEFORE other commands are executed.

(EDIT-) A couple of example programs to show the concept:

```
:::::::::  %userprofile%\desktop\HomeBatch.bat  ::::::::::::::::

@ECHO OFF

:main

Set TestEnvironment=1

Call :targetLabel

:nottarget
ECHO NOT target
pause
exit

:targetLabel
%userprofile%\desktop\OtherBatch.bat npm i

:homeBatch
ECHO returned Home
pause
GOTO main

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::::::::  %userprofile%\desktop\OtherBatch.bat  ::::::::::::::::

@ECHO OFF

:NottheTarget
ECHO NOT THE TARGET
pause
exit

:targetLabel
ECHO Found the Target. TestEnvironment=%TestEnvironment% %~1 %~2
pause
Exit /b

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
echo Y | start /wait /B "C:\Users\Kiriti_Komaragiri\Desktop\sample" npm i
echo Y | start /wait /B "C:\Users\Kiriti_Komaragiri\Desktop\sample2" npm i
```

Comment: Expanding on this, if it's batch to batch, echo Y | CALL "C:\Users\Kiriti_Komaragiri\Desktop\sample2.bat" npm i
also works